# A series of wild cards in STR_DETECT in R

Tags: r, stringr

I use STR_DETECT with IFELSE to create a new column called "function_YN". However, since I have to throw in a large number of wild cards, my script became long and cumbersome. Any way to simply this? Below is just a shortened version of the coding and I actually have more key words to detect.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df$function_YN <- 
ifelse(str_detect(df$JOB_TITLE, "POLICE"),"YES",
ifelse(str_detect(df$JOB_TITLE, "FIREFIGHTER"),"YES",
ifelse(str_detect(df$JOB_TITLE, "DETECTIVE"),"YES",
ifelse(str_detect(df$JOB_TITLE, "PUBLIC SAFETY"),"YES",
ifelse(str_detect(t1$JOB_TITLE, "CAPTAIN"),"YES", "NO")))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of multiple `ifelse` statement, just create a single pattern for the `POLICE`, 'FIREFIGHTER' etc. with `str_c` and then convert the logical to numeric index by adding 1 (`TRUE` -> 1, `FALSE` -> 0 when added 1, changes to 2 and 1 respectively).  Then, using the index as position, replace the position with vector of values (`"NO", "YES"`) - (NOTE: In `R` indexing starts from 1)

```
library(stringr)
yes_words <- c("POLICE", "FIREFIGHTER", "DETECTIVE", "PUBLIC SAFETY", "CAPTAIN")
pat <- str_c("\\b(", str_c(yes_words, collapse = "|"), ")\\b")
df$function_YN <- c("NO", "YES")[ 1 + str_detect(df$JOBTITLE, pat)]
```

Comment: Thanks. What does this part to? str_c("\\b(", str_c(yes_words, collapse = "|"), ")\\b")

Comment: Your codes work well, but I need to create a new column to my dataframe, instead of two vectors (pat, yes_words). How do I do that? Thanks again!

Comment: @SilverSpringbb you just need `df$function_YN <- c("NO", "YES")[ 1 + str_detect(df$JOBTITLE, pat)]`

Comment: The second line creating "pat" can actually be ```pat1 <- str_c(yes_words, collapse = "|")```

Comment: @SilverSpringbb That is already in my post `str_c(yes_words, collapse = "|")` I added the word boundary to avoid any bugs and it can be a bug depending on your condition i.e. if you wants to `FIREFIGHTERS` or `DETECTIVES` along with the same pattern, you can remove the word boundary part.  In most cases, people want the opposite that is the reason I suggested

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative:

```r
str_detect_any <- function(x, target_list) {
   found_any <- rep(FALSE, length(x))
   for (s in target_list) {
      found_any <- found_any | str_detect(x, s)
   }
   return(found_any)
}
```

Then

```r
yes_words <- c("POLICE", "FIREFIGHTER", "DETECTIVE", "PUBLIC SAFETY", "CAPTAIN")
df$function_YN <- ifelse(str_detect_any(df$JOB_TITLE, yes_words), "YES", "NO")
```

(untested). A more compact and less comprehensible version could probably be constructed using `Reduce()` ...

This does require multiple passes through the string. If all of your targets are fixed strings rather than regular expressions, you could use `fixed()` (this is in the documentation for `str_detect`, but I don't actually know how to use it ...), which would make things faster.